# Xcode: Adding Dynamic TextFields at runtime using Tags

Tags: xcode, dynamic

I'm wondering, how to add multiple textfields to a window while it's at runtime.

Code for now:

```
    int numberTextFields = 10;
int x = 300;
int y = 150;
int w = 100;
int h = 30;

for(int i=1; i< numberTextFields; i++)
{
    NSTextField *textField = [[[NSTextField alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+20, y+60, w, h)];
    textField.tag = i;
    [[window contentView] addSubview:textField];
}
```

It works fine for 1 textField, but doesn't add the others...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update the `y` as shown below:

```
int numberTextFields = 10;
int x = 300;
int y = 150;
int w = 100;
int h = 30;

for(int i=1; i< numberTextFields; i++)
{
    NSTextField *textField = [[[NSTextField alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+20, y+60, w, h)];
    textField.tag = i;
    [[window contentView] addSubview:textField];
    y += 40;   // Add this line
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
I added value to "y" but straight to the "y" value... Silly me! 
thx mate!

Comment: You were loading all the textfield at same position and hence couldn't see it. Glad that helped.